Android: Fix Search Text Highlighting with RecyclerView and ListAdapter
I have a SearchView in a Toolbar, that sits above a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  The SearchView works correctly to filter the list based on text inputs. However, the code in the ListAdapter in "onBindViewHolder()" method to highlight the search text with Color.GREEN on each CardView is not working.
I have set up a boolean "isSearchMatched" that toggles to true when a CardView has text that matches the SearchView text.  I then use "isSearchMatched" in onBindViewHolder() plus submitList() with a new ArrayList for ListAdapter to recognize a change to the CardView items so that the search text in the CardView can be highlighted...no luck.
What am I missing here?
MainActivity
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener() {
    ...
    filter(newText)
}

private void filter(String searchText) {
        
    ArrayList<Card> searchList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Card cardItem : mCards) {        
        if (cardItem.getTodo().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {                    
            searchList.add(cardItem);
            **cardItem.setSearchMatched(true);**
        }
    }  
    if (!searchList.isEmpty()) {  
        adapter.setFilter(searchList, searchText);
}

Card.java // model item
@Entity(tableName = "cards_table")
public class Card implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cardId")
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cardTodo")
    private String todo;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cardMatchedSearchText")
    private boolean isSearchMatched = false;

    ...
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeInt(id);
    parcel.writeString(todo);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (isSearchMatched ? 1 : 0));
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();        
    todo = in.readString();
    isSearchMatched = in.readByte() != 0;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public String getTodo() {
    return this.todo;
}
public boolean isSearchMatched() {
    return this.isSearchMatched;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}    
public void setTodo(String todo) {
    this.todo = todo;
}
public void setSearchMatched(boolean isSearchMatched) {
    this.isSearchMatched = isSearchMatched;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Card card = (Card) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, card.id) &&
           Objects.equals(todo, card.todo) &&               
           Objects.equals(isSearchMatched, card.isSearchMatched);
}         
     
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, todo, isSearchMatched);
}    

ListAdapter
public class CardRVAdapter extends ListAdapter<Card, CardRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String searchString = "";
    public Spannable spannable;

    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(Card oldItem, Card newItem) {
        return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(Card oldItem, Card newItem) {
        return oldItem.getTodo().equals(newItem.getTodo()) &&
               oldItem.isSearchMatched() == (newItem.isSearchMatched());
    }
};
    
    public void setFilter(List<Card> newSearchList, String adapSearchText) {

        if (newSearchList != null && !newSearchList.isEmpty()) {
            this.searchString = adapSearchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US);                
            submitList(new ArrayList<>(newSearchList));
        }
    }
  
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cardBlankText2;  // displays text in the CardView and is matched against the user's search text input.
    }

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         
        cardBlankText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankText2);
    }

    void bindData(Card card, final int position) {

        // Highlight matches from search characters is Green color.
        if (searchString != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(searchString)) {
            
            String todoSearchHighlightFromVH = cardBlankText2.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            int offsetEnd2 = todoSearchHighlightFromVH.indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            final Spannable spannable2 = new SpannableString(cardBlankText2.getText());
            spannable2.removeSpan(cardBlankText2);
            cardBlankText2.setText(spannable2);
 
            if (card.isSearchMatched()) {
                for (int start2 = 0; start2 < todoSearchHighlightFromVH.length() && offsetEnd2 != -1; start2 = offsetEnd2 + 1) {

                    offsetEnd2 = todoSearchHighlightFromVH.indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase(Locale.US), start2);
                    if (offsetEnd2 == -1) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        final ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
                        spannable2.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan2, offsetEnd2, offsetEnd2 + searchString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        cardBlankText2.setText(spannable2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }         


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        
        final Card card = getItem(position);
        if (card != null) {        
            holder.bindData(card, position);
        }
    }
}


That's a lot to dig through. Have you tried logging each call to bindData to determine the current set of values for each item in the list ... ?

@dominicoder  I have not yet.  I have a test List of ten CardViews and then I filter that down with the search text to leave 3 CardViews so it should be pretty easy to log.  Do you think that will provide some clues as to why some of the search text is highlighted on some of the 3 CardViews instead of each one?

@AJW Please Check This its same usecase as yours .. if it doesn't solve your problem then let me know .. Your code may required quite a few changes for this .. Using Filterable is better for performance..

You'd implement Filterable, and do the filtration logic by overriding its "getFilter()"

@AJW ListAdapter works with DiffUtil to determine items that are changed with new data set. I don’t find that implementation in your code, can you please double check if you've diff util implementation or not? If not, then can you please try your adapter with diff util once on your code?
Basically, you'll need diff util to compare your card objects to make sure that data has changed and item refreshes accordingly.

Also, if you can debug and check if this condition is valid and passing. if (newSearchList != null && !newSearchList.isEmpty())

@Jeel Vankhede I appreciate your feedback about the card objects changing.  That is the clue I think I need to solve this, because ListAdapter needs to see that the objects have changed (e.g., highlighted or not).  Then the DiffUtil see the changes and redraws the UI to reflect.

@Jeel Vankhede  I updated the model to include a boolean isSearchMatched that toggles to true for any Card item that has search text. No luck yet, any thoughts or ideas on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: You need to think more critically about what is "view" and what is "model" or "data".   The fact that you named your persistent class Card means you are conflating the two.
Now you can call your data class anything you want, but it would make more sense if you called it ToDo instead of naming it after a UI component.  The data exists (is persisted) independently of the view.
This is the whole purpose of the MVVM (Model/View/ViewModel) architectural pattern.  You haven't mentioned anything about a ViewModel, so you end up with a poor separation of concerns among your classes.
I was assuming the SearchView was managing a separate autocomplete for selecting a Card; but now I see what you want is for the "Card"s to be displayed so the user can work with what has been filtered using the SearchView.
I have modified my answer accordingly below.

Disclaimer: This is my highly opinionated solution; there are many other valid solutions possible.

Remove isSearchedMatched property from Card.  This flag only makes sense in the context of the UI.  It does not make sense to persist it because it is always changing based on what the user enters as a search query.

You can add transient UI properties to your Card class, but it might make more sense to have a class like CardUI to hold properties that are needed for the UI but should not be persisted.  I'll proceed with that concept.


Create a CardUI class that includes your Card class as a property.  It will also have the current search string as another property.

I would take the logic to create the highlighted SpannableString and turn that into a helper method on CardUI; e.g. example below

public class CardUI {

    private final String searchText;

    private final Card card;

    public CardUI(String searchText, Card card) {
        this.searchText = searchText;
        this.card = card;
    }

    public Card getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    // SpannableString is used here because it supports equals() comparison needed by adapter
    public SpannableString getHighlight() {

        final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(card.getTodo());
        final String todo = card.getTodo().toLowerCase();

        int index = todo.indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
        while (index != -1) {
            final ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
            spannableString.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan2, index, index + searchText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            index = todo.indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase(), index + searchText.length());
        }

        return spannableString;
    }
}


Change your adapter list type to CardUI.

Now your filter method could look like this:


    ArrayList<CardUI> searchList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Card cardItem : mCards) {        
        if (cardItem.getTodo().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {
            CardUI entry = new CardUI(searchText, cardItem)   
            searchList.add(entry);
        }
    }  


...And your view setting in ViewHolder.bindData() is simply:

      final CardUI item = getItem(position)
      cardBlankText2.setText(item.getHighlight());


Now you need to make sure that the list processing will update the list correctly as the highlighted autocomplete entries change.  Change your differ to this:

private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CardUI> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CardUI>() {
    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(CardUI oldItem, CardUI newItem) {
        return oldItem == newItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(CardUI oldItem, CardUI newItem) {
        // you don't want to get id involved in list comparison, otherwise the list won't update correctly as the user is entering search strings
        return oldItem.getHighlight().equals(newItem.getHighlight());
    }
};

Because you will be rebuilding the highlight strings each time the user types, the RecyclerView should update properly now.

Interesting, will explore. What is "item.second" though?

Also, just confirming is the helper method getHighlightedEntry() within the Card class?  If so, how do I get access in Card to the cardBlankText2 TextView in the adapter's ViewHolder to set up the spannable?

All you need for the autocomplete are the highlighted string (SpannableString) and the id.  I grouped those together using android.util.Pair.  For that instance, pair.first is the id and Pair.second is the spannable string.  Now, you don't have to do it that way, you can create your own utility class with an id property and a highlighted string property (which is more readable than "first" and "second".

Ok, understood on the Pair. second.  The helper class you set up includes the spannable code and I have to apply the spannable to the TextView in the adapter's ViewHoolder code so I am wondering how the helper class can achieve that?

I realized something I didn't account for, I will need to update my answer

Very good, will review and incorporate later today.

I am using ViewModel, Repository, DAO and Room database to persist user entered data.  The data is shown to the user with CardViews in the RecyclerView list.  I like the idea of the CardUI that focuses on views for properties like the search text that do not need to be persisted.  Can you offer a quick example of what the CardUI would look like with the Card class and the searchtext included as a properties?

See my updated answer.

Ok ty.  Will incorporate and hopefully this does it.

Awesome. Glad I could help.

Answer upvoted and bounty awarded...still working on the solution but your approach and code examples, to separate the views and persistence functions, were most helpful.

I use  for the ViewModel, Repository, DAO and Room database for persistence.  When I try to change the adapter's list type to use , I get a conflict error because the MainActivity provides a  to the adapter.submitList(mCards) but it expects  to be submitted.  Please advise.

In item #5 I provided a snippet for the filter method on MainActivity.  You can see that loop takes all the Cards from the MainActivity, constructs CardUIs from them and adds them to the list.  The list is then ready to submit to the adapter.

Thanks, I saw that.  But the original, full List that is supplied to the adapter in MainActivity, before any filtering takes place, now expects  since that is the new list type in the adapter.  The original, full list is supplied with an Observer in MainActivity that looks to the ViewModel and ultilmately gets the data from  and the Room database.  I need to figure out how to transition the MainActivity List that uses  to  used in the adapter.

You can create the CardUIs with an empty (zero-length) string before the user starts typing.  You have to tweak is the filter match condition: Either the Todo contains the string, or the string is empty.  The complication now is that you have to update your list based on your Card observer firing and the user typing.

Ok, nice.  I think I will set the string to empty in the Observer too, then I should be able to use  in MainActivity to draw the initial List in the adapter, before the user types any search text.

The problem is that
            this.searchString = adapSearchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            ArrayList<Card> tempList = new ArrayList<>(newSearchList); 
            submitList(tempList);

it works for remove the item out of the current list, but for existing item on the recycler view, it doesn't trigger onBindViewHolder because the data of the item doesn't change. To fix it, you should add searchString is a property of the Card model, when you filter, you should create new Card model with new search string

Ah, Ok I will review and add the searchString to the model. But what are you recommending in the last sentence where you say "...you should create new Card model with new '"? What is new '?

private void filter(String searchText) {
ArrayList<Card> searchList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Card cardItem : mCards) {

    if (cardItem.getTodo().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {                    
        searchList.add(cardItem.copy(searchString = searchText));
    }
}  
if (!searchList.isEmpty()) {  
    adapter.setFilter(searchList, searchText);

}

Ah, Ok so add "searchString" to the model and that way DiffUtil can see any changes, correct?  And when a  is first created and there is no searchText yet, just add searchString = ""?

Yes, we need the property for DiffUtil can understand the model changed

Ok.  Wouldn't I need a setter in the model to add the searchString as a property to each Card that matches the searchText?  Or does your recommended "...cardItem.copy(searchString = searchText)" automatically update the searchString in the model?

cardItem.copy(...) is a new method added to the model?  What is within that method?

create Kotlin data model, it will auto generate copy method

Unfortunately I don't know any Kotlin and model is already built in Android.  I will post updated code above.

I updated the model to include a boolean isSearchMatched that toggles to true for any Card item that has search text.  No luck yet, any thoughts or ideas on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

The code examples are quite confusing to digest, but this part right here I believe is a significant problem to the logic you're trying to achieve:
    for (Card cardItem : mCards) {        
        if (cardItem.getTodo().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {                    
            searchList.add(cardItem);
            **cardItem.setSearchMatched(true);**
        }
    }  

You are always using the same cardItem reference that already exists and passing it on to your adapter.
What this means is, because cardItem is always the same object and is referenced both in the mCards as well as newSearchList in your adapter, ANY changes you make on the card in the filter(String searchText) will already exist in the CardRVAdapter internal list which is used by the DiffUtil to tell what changed.
As far as I know, submitList(new ArrayList<>(newSearchList)); does not create a deep clone of the list you passed, so the same cardItem object references are kept when passing on to the adapter.
The result of this is by the time the DiffUtil compares its old list to the new one that it receives, the changes in the cardItem are already the same because you are always passing the same object all the time.
At the very least you should change the logic in
searchList.add(cardItem);

to pass a COPY of cardItem with the setSearchMatched changed on the copy instead of passing the same object reference with the modifications already made.
Example:
    for (Card cardItem : mCards) {        
        if (cardItem.getTodo().toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {                    
            Card cardCopy = new Card();
            // copy all the properties of cardItem to cardCopy
            cardCopy.setId(cardItem.id);
            cardCopy.setTodo(cardItem.todo);
            // change the property on the cardCopy only
            cardCopy.setSearchMatched(true);
            // finally add the cardCopy to the searchList
            searchList.add(cardCopy);
        }
    }  

I am not sure if this will be the solution to your issue, but at the very least it is one problem that is preventing your code from working correctly.
You did comment in my DiffUtil ItemCallback areContentsTheSame() always returns true after updating an item on the ListAdapter and it is exactly the same scenario, you're passing the same object reference when you should pass an object copy.

Thanks for the refresh, the same reference has got to be causing the issue.  What would be the best way to pass a copy of the cardItems?

@AJW Unfortunately in Java it has to be a manual process. If it were kotlin it would be really easy. In Java you will have to create a new Card object, copy everything from the existing cardItem and only modify on the new Card object what you want to change. That way when the diffutil compares them both, they will finally have different properties since they will no longer be representing the same object instance.

@AJW One suggestion that helped me big time to avoid these issues; always use lists of immutable objects (objects that cannot change their properties), this way you HAVE to create a new object instance of an existing object when you need to pass changes onto an adapter.

@AJW I've added a rough example of how you could maybe accomplish the object copy using the code sample you provided, hopefully you can understand the idea behind what I explained.

very good I will try that out, cheers.

bindData() seems wrong. For instance:

spannable2.removeSpan(cardBlankText2) makes no sense (although it is benign), since a view is not a span.
quickcard is undefined in the code you have provided. Perhaps you meant card?

Also, the code is pretty complex and may be hiding a bug. The following simplified code may work better:
public void bindData(Card card, final int position) {
    String todoText = card.getTodo();
    cardBlankText2.setText(todoText);

    if (searchString != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(searchString) && card.isSearchMatched()) {
        String todoLowerCase = todoText.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        int startIndex = todoLowerCase.indexOf(searchString);

        if (startIndex != -1) {
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(todoText);
            do {
                int endIndex = startIndex + searchString.length();
                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                startIndex = todoLowerCase.indexOf(searchString, endIndex);
            } while (startIndex != -1);
            cardBlankText2.setText(spannable);
        }
    }
}


Thank you, I will review and test your simplified code.  I did mean "card" (not quickcard).  Also, I attempted to put in removeSpan() as a way to clear any previous spans before adding a new span.  If that is needed then what I have done incorrectly?

I removed the removeSpan code and simplified to your simplified code.  No luck so somehow I don't think onBindViewHolder is being run for those items that match the search text...will have to investigate further.
